# Get TypeScript to infer properties, when implementing a class from an interface?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

If I have bit of a code like:

```
interface Foo {
    foo: (a: number, b: string) => number; 
}


class MyFoo implements Foo {
    foo (a, b) {
        return 99; 
    }
}
```

Then TypeScript warns that `a` and `b` have an implicit 'any' type.

I can explicitly set those types - but I don't want to. I want TypeScript to just the infer the types.

If instead of using a class, I was just using an object, then TS would infer it:

```
const myFoo2: Foo = {
    foo: (a,b) => {
        return 99; 
    }
}
```

Why does TypeScript not infer the types when using the implements and class syntax, and is there a way I can get it to work?

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIyYBcyAFHGSAK4C2ARtADTINkDOYUoA5gJTIAvAD5ktRtADcyXAF9cihABs4HDsgCyATwxZgdAA7KIdCOA16ci-IWJZKrBoLyE3yKBDA0oIZAE5-GVsCBQVcBHQQLmQ6XUwAJjIrIWs3ezJHZ2ExV3cCT29fAKDZNzCgA)

Comment: Looks like the answer is here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41399